# String.PadRight seems to be not working (Unequal columns)

Tags: c#, string, printing

I'm trying to print a receipt. I use this method to put a space between the title and the price:

```
  private string getStringForList(string menu, string price, string title)
    {
        if (price != null)
        {
            decimal Prices = Convert.ToDecimal(price);
            menu = menu.PadRight(33,' ');
            return menu + Prices.ToString("c2");
        }
        else
        {
            return menu.PadRight(46) + title;
        }
    }
```

But it seems that it doesnt work like that. I get this as a result:

[image: link to picture]

How can I print those prices in a line?

Comment: You always add the same padding regardless of how big the menu item is, so it will always appear out of line.

Comment: Just a thought, have you tried something like this to make sure the PadRight is working correctly? `return menu + "test";` just curious about if we're possibly getting some unknown whitespace from the decimal.tostring conversion.

Comment: I also tried   totalWidth - menu.Length

Comment: I tried Test . but its the same. I even tested the menu titles but the dont have a unknown character either.

Comment: Are you using a fixed-width font? Otherwise you will never be able to align the columns counting the spaces needed. As you can see In your image the word 'doner' and the word 'donne' (both 5 chars) are not of equal length.

Comment: @Steve i declared a font like this             Font smallItemFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
and i use it for all of them .

Comment: Arial is a variable-width font thus doesn't align counting spaces. If you want to use this technique then you should choose a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: You are awesome man. that solved the problem . i used Courier New and its works. will you make this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I checked, the padding adds up to 33. So the issue must be that the font's blank spaces must be more narrow than other text. Maybe you could try using tab jumps ('\t') or a font that has the same width for all characters, including blanks.